# Products are OUT OF STOCK

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock

OUT OF STOCK ISSUE:-

Some Downloadable Products are OUT OF STOCK in Product Page, AT the same time In Product Detail Page. Same Downloadable Products showing the Instock. What the reason of showing the out of stock in Product Page. please help me!

Comment: Please do an indexing from index Management from admin

Comment: @Amit Bera, I did, but no luck still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear cache and reindex `cataloginventory_stock` Stock Status from admin panel

> Magento System > Cache management

Also if you are using any server level cache then just purge it and then check the stock status in browser with hard refresh.

Try with different browser clearing cache.

Comment: I have already cleared all the cache and reindex. Still Not solving the issue.. It's Happening When the downloadable Products are edit or create the new product, that product having the issue. out of stock in product list page, the detailpage its Instock!

Comment: @Crock In this case you need to reindex stock status just after adding product.
1. Cache Refresh
2. Reindex
3. Setting up stock correctly
4. Config settings for catalog 
This are the for main thing to consider when you see out of stock issue on product pages. but in case this wont help you need to check with recently added extension or your custom code and compiler status which may cause issue.

Comment: Your Correct, The issue comes from the new extension only. i was uninstalled, only its working usually